# Having trouble understanding this javascript destructuring statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm working with a react/redux sample project and since I'm kind of new to Javascript, my exposure to some of the shorthanded ES6 javascript is limited. 
The statement I am having trouble following is this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { selectedSubreddit, postsBySubreddit } = state;

  // This part here is confusing to me
  const { isFetching, lastUpdated, items: posts } = postsBySubreddit[
    selectedSubreddit
  ] || {
    isFetching: true,
    items: []
  };

  return {
    selectedSubreddit,
    posts,
    isFetching,
    lastUpdated
  };
}
```

I mostly understand the purpose of this function but I'm not sure what's going on in that part that I have a comment in.

What I gathered so far is that postsBySubreddit is an array that we are getting an element from based on selectedSubreddit. From that element, we are 'extracting' `isFetching`, `lastUpdated`, and `items` (while aliasing it to `posts` simultaneously). The thing that throws me off is the `||` operator and the statement that follows it in the curly braces.

Is this an OR condition? If it is, are we saying that if postsBySubreddit[selectedSubreddit] === undefined, we're giving isFetching the value of true and items an empty array?

Comment: The `||` is there in case `postsBySubreddit[selectedSubreddit]` is `undefined`

Comment: You probably meant *destructuring* statement.

Comment: Read the answers for what is happening but keep in mind that it would be more readable to use default values for the destructuring `const { isFetching = true, lastUpdated, items: posts = [] } = postsBySubreddit[ selectedSubreddit ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is *almost* correct. Until the `||` operator, you're correct. But for the `||` operator,

> if postsBySubreddit[selectedSubreddit] === **undefined**, we're giving isFetching the value of true and items an empty array

Not necessarily `undefined`, if `postsBySubreddit[selectedSubreddit]` is falsy, e.g. `0`, `''`, `false`, `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`. Note that `[]` and `{}` are truthy. (to easily check if you've forgotten, you can type `!!NaN` in the dev console or node interpreter).

`let a = b || c` is equivalent to:

```
let a;
if (b)
  a = b;
else
  a = c;
```

Similarly, `let a = b || {x: 0, y: 1}` is equivalent to

```
let a;
if (b)
  a = b;
else
  a = {x: 0, y: 1};
```

Comment: Just one more thing to add... In javascript, `if(b)` returns `false` if b === false or if b is empty - does not have any value in there. So it's a way to always return not empty value.

Answer (score 1):

The `||` operator means to run the next statement if the previous one is false.

Just look at this:

```
if (thing == "ok" || otherthing == "notok") {
```

I think that you know what this means. Enter the block if either statement is `true`. The way it "runs" is by first checking the left statement (`thing == "ok"`) and if is false, then run the next statement (`otherthing == "notok"`).

The same thing can be done to assign to variables:

```
var result = thing == "ok" || otherthing == "notok";
```

This thing will make result be `true` if the left or right statement returns `true`, following the same logic as I explained above.

Now, if we go further with this logic, we can do this:

```
var result = FIRST_STATEMENT || SECOND_STATEMENT;
```

This will run the `FIRST_STATEMENT`, get the value and check if is not `false`. If the result is not false, will run the `SECOND_STATEMENT` and return the value. if the `FIRST_STATEMENT` is not `false`, will return that value instead (because will not run the `SECOND_STATEMENT`).

**In short**, the `||` operator will evaluate statements from left to right and return the first one that is not `false`.

PD: Note that `null`, `undefined`, `""`, `NaN` and `0` is the same as a `false` statement.

PD2: To clarify, none of these values will be triple equal (`===`) to each other.